# Shared library from archive (.a) file in C

Tags: c, linux, makefile, shared-libraries

I was given a task to create archive file **.a** from objects file and create a shared library file from archive .a file. I have tried experiment having following file:
**foo.h**

```
#ifndef _foo_h__
#define _foo_h__
extern void foo(void);
extern void bar(void); 
#endif //_foo_h__
```

**foo.c**

```
#include<stdio.h>

void foo(void)
{
    puts("Hello, I'm a shared library");
}
```

**bar.c**

```
#include<stdio.h>

void bar(void)
{
    puts("This is bar function call.");
}
```

**main.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include"foo.h"

int main(void)
{
    puts("This is a shared library test...");
    foo();
    bar();
    return 0;
}
```

**Makefile**

```
CFLAGS = -Wall -Werror
LDFLAGS = -L/home/betatest/Public/implicit-rule-archive -Wl,-rpath,'$$ORIGIN'

all : run

run : main.o libfoo.so
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $^

libfoo.so : CFLAGS += -fPIC # Build objects for .so with -fPIC.
libfoo.so : libfoo.a
    $(CC) -shared -o $@ $^

libfoo.a : foo.o bar.o
    ar cvq libfoo.a foo.o bar.o
#   ar cr libfoo.a foo.o bar.o

# Compile any .o from .c. Also make dependencies automatically.
%.o : %.c
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $<

#Include dependencies on subsequent builds.

.PHONY : all clean

clean :
    -rm -f *.o *.d run libfoo.*
```

This simple test program seems to run fine but while compiling using make it producing error as:

```
cc -c -Wall -Werror -o main.o main.c
cc -c -Wall -Werror -fPIC  -o foo.o foo.c
cc -c -Wall -Werror -fPIC  -o bar.o bar.c
ar cvq libfoo.a foo.o bar.o
a - foo.o
a - bar.o
cc -shared -o libfoo.so libfoo.a
cc -L/home/betatest/Public/implicit-rule-archive -Wl,-rpath,'$ORIGIN' -o run main.o libfoo.so
main.o: In function `main':
main.c:(.text+0xf): undefined reference to `foo'
main.c:(.text+0x14): undefined reference to `bar'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile-test:7: recipe for target 'run' failed
make: *** [run] Error 1
```

Somebody please point out that where I am getting wrong?? Thanks a lot.

Comment: You don't link the shared library: try `-lfoo` instead of `libfoo.so`

Comment: cc is getting the literal single quotes around $ORIGIN.  Try omitting them.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you wish to build a shared library from a static library you have to tell the linker to use all function/symbols included in static library (.a). Otherwise nothing will be included in the shared library (.so).

You have to use `--whole-archive/--no-whole-archive` pair in linking.

```
CFLAGS = -Wall -Werror
LDFLAGS = -L/home/betatest/Public/implicit-rule-archive -Wl,-rpath,'$$ORIGIN'

all : run

run : main.o libfoo.so
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $^

libfoo.so : CFLAGS += -fPIC # Build objects for .so with -fPIC.
libfoo.so : libfoo.a
    $(CC) -shared -o $@ -Wl,--whole-archive $^  -Wl,--no-whole-archive

libfoo.a : foo.o bar.o
     ar cvq libfoo.a foo.o bar.o

# Compile any .o from .c. Also make dependencies automatically.
%.o : %.c
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $<

#Include dependencies on subsequent builds.

.PHONY : all clean

clean :
    -rm -f *.o *.d run libfoo.*
```

You can check the exported functions using `nm` command:

```
$ nm -D libfoo.so | grep  ' T '
0000000000000702 T bar
0000000000000714 T _fini
00000000000006f0 T foo
0000000000000590 T _init
```

When no `--whole-archive/--no-whole-archive` pair is used you get:

```
$ nm -D libfoo.so | grep  ' T '
0000000000000714 T _fini
0000000000000590 T _init
```

Comment: Thanks @ctheo sir!!!!!! The compilation goes smoothly and the output of the compilation is:                         `cc -c -Wall -Werror -o main.o main.c  ;
cc -c -Wall -Werror -fPIC  -o foo.o foo.c ;
cc -c -Wall -Werror -fPIC  -o bar.o bar.c ;
ar cvq libfoo.a foo.o bar.o ;
a - foo.o ;
a - bar.o ;
cc -shared -o libfoo.so -Wl,--whole-archive libfoo.a  -Wl,--no-whole-archive ;
cc -L/home/betatest/Public/implicit-rule-archive -Wl,-rpath,'$ORIGIN' -o run main.o libfoo.so ;`
I want to ask how main.o is generated is it implicit rule or pattern defined below? Thanks!!

Comment: The main.o is build by the command `cc -c -Wall -Werror -o main.o main.c`. It uses CFLAGS without `-fPIC` addition since `libfoo.so` does not depend on it.

Comment: It means it see a dependency main.o and call the defined pattern rule `%.o : %.c` . Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your mistake is in the question: do not make shared library from archive, make it from objects, i.e. change Makefile like this

```
libfoo.so : foo.o bar.o
    $(CC) -shared -o $@ foo.o bar.o
```

you can also use `%.o` to mean all objects

also you need `CFLAGS = -fPIC` globally, to affect compilation command, not only the link step, that is you .o object files should be position-independent.

also here `extern` is not needed, all C functions are implicitly extern

```
extern void foo(void);
```

I would also not recommend using `rpath` and better

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=.
```

to load .so from current directory (or export path to .so's directory)